# How to get the highest tier out of a list of things?

Tags: python, api

I am currently taking data from an API, I was wondering if there is a way to get multiple highest tier from the list as shown below? (The beginning of the string is the type of thing and the end is the tier)

['ACACIA_1', 'ACACIA_10', 'ACACIA_11', 'ACACIA_2', 'ACACIA_3', 'ACACIA_4', 'ACACIA_5', 'ACACIA_6', 'ACACIA_7', 'ACACIA_8', 'ACACIA_9', 'BIRCH_1', 'BIRCH_10', 'BIRCH_11', 'BIRCH_2', 'BIRCH_3', 'BIRCH_4', 'BIRCH_5', 'BIRCH_6', 'BIRCH_7', 'BIRCH_8', 'BIRCH_9', 'BLAZE_1', 'BLAZE_10', 'BLAZE_2', 'BLAZE_3', 'BLAZE_4', 'BLAZE_5', 'BLAZE_6', 'BLAZE_7', 'BLAZE_8', 'BLAZE_9']

Comment: I think you'll get better answers if you rephrase the question to not require the knowledge of what "Hypixel", "minions" and "tiers" are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a `key` of `max` function:

```
>>> max(minions, key=lambda m: int(m.split('_')[1]))
'ACACIA_11'
```

To get the maximums for each type, you can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

type_getter = lambda x: x.split('_')[0]
tire_getter = lambda m: int(m.split('_')[1])

{g: max(v, key=tire_getter) for g, v in groupby(minions, type_getter)}
```

Output:

```
{'ACACIA': 'ACACIA_11', 'BIRCH': 'BIRCH_11', 'BLAZE': 'BLAZE_10'}
```

Comment: It works for 1 type but is there any way to make it work for multiple types?

Comment: What are "multiple types"?

Comment: So like the list above has acacia, birch, blaze, etc is there any way for it to work with all of them?